# problem in connecting to mysql wamp and django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, wamp, mysql-connector

I have a problem in connect mysql wamp to django using mysql connector

Hi , I Have a database in mysql and i want to connect it to django with mysqlconnector library :
I tries these : 
Step 1 :

```
pip install mysqlconnector
```

Step 2 : 
then change settings.py like this :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django', 
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

after this i run the server using :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and at the end i got this error :

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x04B39C00>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 203, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 336, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What can i do for this problem ? 
any suggestions will be helpfull , thank you .

Comment: `pip install mysqlconnector ` instead of  `pip install mysql-connector `?

Comment: @jiaJimmy just a typing mistake , i changed that but not worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and asking alot , i found the solution .

first i need to install build tools of microsoft .(this is available in microsoft visual studio package )  .

and then i downgrade my python version from 3.7.2 to 3.5.6  .

and then i use this command to install mysqlclient :

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```

this is ok , and myproblem solved  .